# JavaRX: How to return cached value immediately and in parallel do a network request

Tags: java, kotlin, rx-java, reactive-programming

How do I yield a previous cached value immediately while I am waiting to receive a network request?

```
    val suggestionsCache = mutableMapOf<String, List<Suggestion>>()

    override fun requestSuggestions(queryString: String, queryLocation: Location): Observable<List<Suggestion>> {
        return Observable.merge(
                getCached(queryString),
                placesService
                        .requestSuggestions(queryString, queryLocation)
                        .doOnNext { cache(it, queryString) })
    }

    private fun getCached(queryString: String): Observable<List<Suggestion>?>? {
        return if (suggestionsCache.containsKey(queryString)) Observable.just(suggestionsCache[queryString]) else Observable.never<List<Suggestion>>()
    }

    private fun cache(suggestions: List<Suggestion>, queryString: String) {
        suggestionsCache[queryString] = suggestions
    }
```

It is about the `requestSuggestions` method. It should yield an immediate result from the cache if possible and still run a request to the `placeService` so that the user will see suggestions right away but then also gets an updated list after the request terminates.

The code above does not yield any element when subscribing. What am I missing?